# Android working HttpRequest Class

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a working `HtttpRequest` Class , so that I can do it like this:

```
String response = Request.get("http://google.com");
```

I already wrote a Class but it doesn't work on `Android 3+` but on 2.3 it does.

```
public class WebRequest {
public String get(String url){
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        // Create a response handler
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);


        return responseBody;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

}

Please help!!!

Comment: is it working in 2.3 ?? if so check wether the error is strictmode policy if so shift it to an async task

Comment: it probably has something with the encoding , try passing it a utf-8 encoded url

Comment: Please show the code, that is not working.

Comment: The URL is utf-8 encoded. It is working on 2.3. Can you shift it to an async task? I don't know how to do it that I can return a response directly...

Answer (score 1):

You could look at this answer: [How do I use the Simple HTTP client in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457492/simple-http-example-in-android/4457526#4457526).

There they use these two methods:

```
public static void connect(String url) 
{

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Prepare a request object
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

    // Execute the request
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        // Examine the response status
        Log.i("Praeda",response.getStatusLine().toString());

        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
        // to worry about connection release

        if (entity != null) {

            // A Simple JSON Response Read
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
            // now you have the string representation of the HTML request
            instream.close();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
{

    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

***UPDATE***

Using AsyncTask: [Android HTTP Request AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8829321/2140191)

***UPDATE 2 - SIMPLE VERSION***

```
    public class XmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    public String doInBackground(String... urls){
        String url = urls[0];

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Prepare a request object
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

        // Execute the request
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            // Examine the response status
            Log.i("Praeda",response.getStatusLine().toString());

            // Get hold of the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
            // to worry about connection release

            if (entity != null) {

                // A Simple JSON Response Read
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
                // now you have the string representation of the HTML request
                instream.close();
            }

                return xml;
            }
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String xml){
        // Your XML parsing statement here
    }
}
```

After creating this class (and creating your own xml parser?!) use the following:

```
String result = new XmlTask().execute("http://google.com");
```

Comment: I think you have to use AsyncTask on Android 3+.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for @user1849921 ? [Android HTTP Request AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8829321/2140191)

Comment: Yes but how do I directly return the response that I can go on with it where I started the execution?

Comment: Like it is mentioned in the answer: `YourClassExtendingJSONTask task = new YourClassExtendingJSONTask();
task.execute(url);` Meaning that you have to create another class (for example: YourClassExtendingJSONTask.class) and extend the JSONTask class. Furthermore you have to implement your own `customMethod(JSONObject json)` method in the YourClassExtendingJSONTask.class.

Comment: yes but I need the response as string

Comment: Like String response = task.execute(url)

Comment: Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I'll update my answer so it's easier to see...

Comment: I see... Is there no easier way? That makes it lot more complicated for me...

Comment: Ok'll give it another try...