# Connecting to external database in android

Tags: android, database, json, connection

I am trying to connect to my database on my localhost through my android application. I have created a php file and stored it in my wamp/www/myfolder, when I run it it works fine, so it must be a problem with my android class.

```
   public void getData(){
    String result ="";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new        HttpPost("http://localhost/testdata/getAllCustomers.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection");
        resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
```

I have gone over my code many times but I can't find the problem.
I have created two morw try catches in this method that convert the result and the other one parses the data but when I run it the first log appears so it doesn't connect to the database.

P.s I am using eclipse, to I need a plugin for json, I know eclipse IDE supports it.

Comment: I get a warning from System.err on HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); but I don't understand why and also i get the log I created.

Comment: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException that my error but don't really know what it is

Comment: Thanks Keyser, I know it may be a duplicate but I am new to this site and I don't know how everything really works. Sorry for that.

Comment: No problem :p You gotta start somewhere.

Comment: I have found the solution, Because I am using an android version over 9 I had to use StrictMode in my onCreare method.

   

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
  }

Answer found from
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Read the comments on that answer, then read my answer :p It's a dangerous workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` means that you are attempting to perform a network operation on the main thread, which is forbidden. Simply do it from another thread. This is mainly done by creating an AsyncTask. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/645270) an example. And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8829321/645270) another one.

It's worth noting that [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher, but the behaviour is always heavily discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

The loopback address in case of android when you are trying to connect from emulator is 10.0.2.2

i.e instead of localhost use 10.0.2.2

Comment: Thanks Santhosh for your answer but it didn't change anything.