# Code in Genymotion does not work in Android Studio

Tags: java, php, android, genymotion

I have login code that works perfectly fine in genymotion and it just won't run on android studio. In genymotion he username and password are found in the database and I am able to login while in android studio it keeps saying there is a syntax error in the php file. I have already copy pasted the same code for everything and it is still giving me the same error.

```
  package com.example.login2;


 import java.util.ArrayList;


  import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
  import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class login2 extends Activity {
EditText un,pw;
TextView error;
Button ok;
protected String macAddress;
protected String IPAddress;
protected String version;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

// public void LoggedIn(View view) {
// Do something in response to button
//       Intent intent = new Intent(this, Logout.class);
//       startActivity(intent);
//  }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_un);
    pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
    ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    error=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error);
    macAddress = CustomHttpClient.getMacAddress(getBaseContext());
    IPAddress = CustomHttpClient.getIP(getBaseContext());
    version = CustomHttpClient.getAndroidVersion();




    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", un.getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pw.getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MacAddress",macAddress.toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IPAddress",IPAddress.toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Version",version.toString()));
            //String valid = "1";
            String response = null;
            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://192.168.1.7/thesis/check.php", postParameters);
                String res=response.toString();
                // res = res.trim();
                res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                //error.setText(res);

                if(res.equals("1")){
                    error.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Logged in ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    //startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    //startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    // startActivity(startMain);
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(login2.this, Logout.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                else{
                    error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, wrong Username/Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should take a look about Asynchronous Tasks in Android:

[Android HTTP Request AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829135/android-http-request-asynctask)

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

And, as you said "while in android studio it keeps saying there is a syntax error in the php file", that syntax error is in your php file and you are just reading the HTTP response message.

In addition, I recommend you to read about webservices and their secure implementation. It's not much secure to ask for a number "1 or 0" and do the check against that response.

[Secure Web Services: REST over HTTPS vs SOAP + WS-Security. Which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853620/secure-web-services-rest-over-https-vs-soap-ws-security-which-is-better)

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html